# UIButton Text Only Appearing On Touch

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've set up a UIButton as follows:

```
let scanButton = UIButton()

func setUpScanButton (scanButton: UIButton) -> () {
    scanButton.addTarget(self, action: "goToScanner" , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    scanButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    scanButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    scanButton.setTitle("Scan", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    scanButton.frame = CGRectMake(36, 385, self.view.frame.width - 41, 30)
    scanButton.center.x = CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds)
    scanButton.center.y = CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds)
    scanButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    self.view.addSubview(scanButton)
}
setUpScanButton(scanButton)
```

The issue is that the text does not appear until the touch is applied to the button. I tried editing the color of both the text and the button but to no avail.

Comment: I just run it there the text Scan shows fine

Comment: By the way, instead of `UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside`, you can put `.TouchUpInside`. Same with `UIControlState.Normal` -> `.Normal`.

Comment: And you also can remove the " -> ()" in the function declaration

Comment: Where is your button defined ? Is it in an asynchronous task ? If yes that may be why. All UI elements need to be drawn on the main thread. In order to do that you can put your code inside an `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { //Your code })`

Comment: @TheTom : That was this issue, thanks! I did not realize that UI elements had to be drawn to the main thread.

Comment: Added the comment as an answer for future users stumbling on this thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your button is most probably drawn on a secondary thread. So it won't be drawn at the right time.

To be correctly drawn and at the right time, all UI elements have to be drawn on the main thread.

You can achieve that with the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    // Insert your code to add the button here
})
```

**In Swift 3 & 4:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Insert your code to add the button here
}
```